# Configure OutputCache for ASCX from web.config's cache profiles

Tags: caching, outputcache, ascx, cacheprofile

To configure aspx pages' OutputCache from one place, there is a great tool which is the **CacheProfile** attribute in **<%@ OutputCache %>** associated with a custom cache profile defined in the **web.config** :

```
<caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="myProfile" duration="300"  />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

And the line :

```
<%@ OutputCache CacheProfile="myProfile" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

does the job.
But **how to do the same thing for ascx user controls ?**
CacheProfile isn't in <%@ OutputCache %> :S
Is there a workaround ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx :

"Either this attribute (VaryByParam) or the VaryByControl attribute is required when you use the @ OutputCache directive on ASP.NET pages and user controls. A parser error occurs if you fail to include it."